# VLC media player won't advance beyond what already played

Tags: vlc-media-player

I'm trying to watch some long (multi-hour) .FLV video files using VLC.  But I can't drag the slider or use the Jump to Time feature for anything beyond what the player has already played (I guess what's in the cache).  Any suggestions?

Comment: I believe that's caused by a bad encoding in the video.  Sometimes a codec doesn't have the metadata "map" of the video's time scale, or a video might have missing or corrupted metadata (usually from the end of the file).  When this happens, it can only render procedurally because it needs to know what it immediately played in order to render the next frames.

Comment: You will want to get the exact error message from the VLC debug console. Open VLC, choose Tools > Messages > set verbosity to 2 (debug.) Now, play the video where it breaks and you should get an error message in here to search for.